# How to solve this Morse code like puzzle

Tags: puzzle-identification, geocaching

I am trying to solve [this Puzzle based Geocache](https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC5914J_dots-and-dashes-ii).

It is simply this string on dots and dashes

> --.-..-....-.---...--.--.---..-..--..-..---.--.--..--..--.---..-..---.-..--..-..--..---.-..---..--.--..-.---..---.--.---.--.--..--..---.-...--.-..---..--.--.--..--..--..-.---..--.---..-..-..--..---.-..---.--..--..-..---.---..-.--..---.--..-..--...---.-.--

Initially I thought it might be Morse code, however I'm not sure as there is no way to determine where the spaces are. I've been unable to find something that is this close to morse code.

There is one hint with is:

> Fence not ladder

The answer to this puzzle should be a set of GPS coordinates. (Most likely is this format: N 54° 58.300' W 001° 35.075')

Comment: I believe it is either going to be fractionated morse code in which case this is going to be difficult to break. However the clue seems to indicate that it is a rail fence cipher. Interesting....

Comment: In fact there is a chance it could be both of those... I'll see if that gives anything...

Comment: what kind of gps coordinate? that is critical.

Comment: @Oray I've updated the question

Comment: this coordinate is close to your location since geocache is that kind of game? if so could you give us your approximate coordinate?

Comment: Yes the final coordinates would typically be within a couple of miles of the coordinates given above.

Comment: Doesn't look like true Morse code because there are many more `-` dashes (140) than `.` dots (115). If I remember, Morse was devised to use slightly more dots than dashes because dots take less time.

Comment: if it helps this is part of a small series and here are the other two... https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC57F4A_dots-and-dashes https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC5B1BD_dots-and-dashes-iii

Comment: @humn: That presumable assumes standard english words/sentences. I believe that there are 14 morse letters that have equal or more dashes than dots and you could probably easily form some kind of coded message that uses the majority those. Likewise numbers have an equal spread of dashes and dots so something numeric could easily not have a typical spread (though the strucure here doesn't lend itself to being lots of digits).

Comment: Well, I went and solved it. It's not Morse code. The hint actually was helpful, as was the "related web page". However, as a fellow geocacher, I really don't feel like spoiling the solution here. That just seems to go against the etiquette, and probably against the wishes of the cache owner. Mystery caches aren't supposed to be *that* easily solvable by googling. (In fact, given that it's a premium cache, even just posting the encoded coordinates here in your question might be considered kind of bad form. After all, presumably the CO had some reason to make it premium in the first place.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Congrats, however I'm not necessarily after the answer, a nod in the right direction doesn't seem bad form to me.

Comment: Hmm. A hint would certainly seem more reasonable, but I'm not sure what I more I could say than I already did without spoiling the solution outright. Once you figure out what the code actually is, the solution is really quite trivial. (I suppose that kind of counts as a minor hint in itself.)

Comment: OK so i think i have it...well i certainly have some usable coords so thank you!

Now I'm wondering if indeed this is the right place for these puzzles as now although I want to share the solution it would indeed be bad form but it's also the point of this site..

Comment: FWIW, I posted [a question about the appropriateness of geocaching puzzles here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6079/are-puzzles-taken-from-mystery-geocaches-on-topic-here-and-if-yes-how-to-prope) on the meta site. Feel free to chime in there if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this and have less than 50 rep, that's why I am leaving a comment as an answer. I'm sorry.

This could be binary. dash = 1, dot = 0.
Also, it is exactly 255 characters long.

Comment: Good spot! Welcome to PSE. I'd say this is the beginning of an answer: if you convert the code into binary, and from there convert it into ASCII using an online interpreter, then this would be a fully-fledged answer. It may not necessarily be the *correct* answer, but it would be a good attempt.

Comment: Hey @Vuudi, thanks for your answer. It's a good one but wouldn't the fact that 8 doesn't go into 255 stop it from being binary?